# apache mod_rewrite from /a/b/c to /a.php?arg1=b&arg2=c

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to do a rewrite.  After reading the URL Rewriting Guide, I'm still a bit confused. 
I want to take /blog/123 and make it become /blog.php?blog=123, but I cannot figure out why it's not working.  I know that mod_rewrite is on.  My .htaccess  file is:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/blog/([^/]+)/?$  /blog.php?blog=$1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue.  I was making it way too hard.

```
RewriteCond /blog/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /blog/([0-9]+)$ /blog.php?blog=$1
```

The first thing I needed to to was set the condition.  The %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d variable means  to run the rule if the directory is non-existant.  It then matches on a number to the end of the string.